# Some info relates to prerelease product that may be substantially modified before it’s released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to find some documentations about the "ShareLink" SharePoint REST api end point, and i found the below 2 links :-

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharinglinkkind?view=sharepoint-csom
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharing.role?view=sharepoint-csom

But I have the following 2 questions: -

1. Are those also related to the "ShareLink" SharePoint REST api end point? or they only relate to SharePoint CSOM API?
2. Why both links have this message in blue displayed, and what this message means: -

[image]

Thanks